# How to use matColumnDef of material table and *ngFor to get product with corresponding category

Tags: angular, webapi

I have a structure table of material library Angular, I want to show that each product has a name category by productTypeId from product table. I am trying to use `*ngFor` to get all productTypes by using the foloowing statement:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="productTypeId" *ngFor="let c of productType">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product Type </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.productTypeId == c.id? c.name:"error" }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

But I am getting an error. `ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "productTypeId".`

[Picture of methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiR8I.png)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `columns: displayedColumns;` on `tr` tag like this:

```
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

also define displayedColumns in ts file (be sure to add productTypeId):

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['productTypeId', 'other columns'];
```

see this mat-table [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#table-basic)

Comment: thanks for the reply but i already have all the above, basically the table doesn't error, it just fails when i try to add *ngFor to get the product type name